# Could not find error in CUDA vector addition program

Tags: cuda

[image]

**Output**:

```
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

Comment: If you want help, you need to provide the shortest example which illustrates the problem you have (see [MCVE]). I can't compile your screen shot and run it for myself.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please check how you set the size of each memory space you allocated. Sometimes you set it to be `size`, sometimes be `N*size`.

Comment: @user2086564 You should refine your questions though. At least paste the code text to it, rather than a screenshot.